# How to get all of the unique sets of dictionaries based on value?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like the following.

```
mylist = [{'fname': 'a', 'lname': '1'},
          {'fname': 'b', 'lname': '2'},
          {'fname': 'c', 'lname': '3'},
          {'fname': 'd', 'lname': '3'},
          {'fname': 'e', 'lname': '4'},
          {'fname': 'f', 'lname': '4'}]
```

I want to find all of the different sets of entries which cover all of the *lname* property. For instance, the desired result is:

```
result = [
             [{'fname': 'a', 'lname': '1'},
              {'fname': 'b', 'lname': '2'},
              {'fname': 'c', 'lname': '3'},
              {'fname': 'e', 'lname': '4'}],

             [{'fname': 'a', 'lname': '1'},
              {'fname': 'b', 'lname': '2'},
              {'fname': 'c', 'lname': '3'},
              {'fname': 'f', 'lname': '4'}],

             [{'fname': 'a', 'lname': '1'},
              {'fname': 'b', 'lname': '2'},
              {'fname': 'd', 'lname': '3'},
              {'fname': 'e', 'lname': '4'}],

             [{'fname': 'a', 'lname': '1'},
              {'fname': 'b', 'lname': '2'},
              {'fname': 'd', 'lname': '3'},
              {'fname': 'f', 'lname': '4'}]
        ]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Why are fnames not consistent in the example output?

Comment: Separate the dicts by `lname` so you have four lists of dicts.  Use `itertools.product` to get the combinations you want.

Comment: I was just gonna mention product it’s exactly how I’d solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at `itertools` as the others suggested. For me `combinations` did the job. Looks like the order of the result is the same.

```
from itertools import combinations

combs = combinations(mylist, 4)

result = []
for item in combs:
    x = list(item)
    y = []
    for dic in item:
        y += list(dic.values())
    if len(set(y)) is 8: # lists with duplicate values are excluded 
        result.append(x)

result
```

Comment: Wow, this is way simpler than my answer! Nice! You can even make it simpler: Firstly we only care about the lnames, so swap out `y` for `lnames = (d['lname'] for d in item)`, then the len should be less than 4: `if len(set(lnames)) == 4`. Secondly, `x` is not really used, so just cast to `list` when needed: `result.append(list(item))`. I even got it down to one line, though it's hard to read: `result = [list(i) for i in combs if len(set(d['lname'] for d in i)) == 4]`

Comment: Correction, *"we only care about the lnames"* should have been "only the lnames need to be unique"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the dicts by lname, then use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the product of the groups of dicts.

I'm also using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to simplify getting lnames and [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to print the result.

```
from itertools import groupby, product
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

get_lname = itemgetter('lname')
mylist.sort(key=get_lname)  # Ensure "mylist" is in sorted order
groups = groupby(mylist, key=get_lname)
just_groups = (list(g) for k, g in groups)
result = [list(i) for i in product(*just_groups)]
pprint(result)
```

`result` is the same as the one in the question.

Still I'm pretty sure it could be improved, just not sure how.